# How to return an error code with ValidationResult asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I need to differentiate between errors in my front end by sending back an error code from the validation.

Currently errors will just send back the `string errorMessage`, from something like

`return new ValidationResult("Some error message")`.

Can i somehow send back an error code, using an enum of error types for me to check in front end?

Theoretical Example:

`return new ValidationResult("Some default error message", MyErrorEnum.notEnoughCats)`

Answer (score 1):

it's easy. only it is better to use constants as digits. You need:

```
  /// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public class NotFoundException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Сообщение об ошибке
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message"></param>
    public NotFoundException(string message, int? codeAction=null) : base(message)
    {
        CodeAction = codeAction;
    }

    public int? CodeAction { get; set; }
}
```

when intercept an error :

```
 public class ErrorsFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute, IAutofacExceptionFilter
{
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{  
       var errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); 
       if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is NotFoundException)
        {
            errorMessage.ErrorCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            isWarning = true;
            errorMessage.CodeAction = ((NotFoundException) actionExecutedContext.Exception).CodeAction; 
        }
          actionExecutedContext.Response = actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)errorMessage.ErrorCode, errorMessage);
}
}
```

errorMessage it's my return class

```
  /// <summary>
    /// HTTP Code
    /// </summary>
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// коде ошибки внутри сервиса
    /// </summary>
    public int? CodeAction { get; set; }
```

simple errors

```
{  "errorCode": 400,  "codeAction": 2,  "errors": {
"error": "bad values!"  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this way if ajax + json

```
private string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model, Dictionary<string, object> oDicParametresViewData = null, string sHtmlFieldPrefix = "")
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        if (oDicParametresViewData != null) foreach (var param in oDicParametresViewData) ViewData[param.Key] = param.Value;
        if (sHtmlFieldPrefix != "") ViewData.TemplateInfo = new System.Web.Mvc.TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = sHtmlFieldPrefix };
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }

 Response.StatusCode = 666;

 return Json(new
        {
            Html = RenderRazorViewToString("view", model),            
        });
```

who call your validation result ?
you can also return a partial view ?