# How can we extend the IValidatableObject class to return a Custom object instead of ValidationResult?

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I need to perform business validations on my model that implements the IValidatableObject Interface which contains a Validate method that returns an IEnumerable of ValidationResult.
I want to return a subclass of ValidationResult that not just have ErrorMessage but also the ErrorCode as a different property.

Comment: If `yourSubClass` inherits from `ValidationResult`, there is no problem? You can cast the resulting `ValidationResults` to your subclasses in the client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return an error code with ValidationResult asp .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031638/how-to-return-an-error-code-with-validationresult-asp-net)